# Unable to move UIWebView to a specified section in iOS11 (iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, ios11

We have used the below lines of code to move to the web view:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.hash=\'#-1\';"]];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.hash=\'#%@\';", index]];
```

but somehow this code doesn't work only in iPad. Here is how I initialised the web view:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];
[webView setBackgroundColor:WHITECOLOR];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview: webView];
```

Could someone please guide me how to debug it.

Comment: In iOS11 `location.hash` seems to be broken, but it's a simple solution to this.
Insted using usual combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS11 `location.hash` seems to be broken, but it's a simple solution to this.
Instead using an usual combination:

```
location.hash = "";
location.hash = _some_hash_string_
```

use javascript below:

```
var hashElement=document.getElementsByName(_some_hash_string_)[0];
if(hashElement) {
    hashElement.scrollIntoView();
} else { 
    // if the element is not found - scroll to top
    document.documentElement.scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

Comment: Having javascript code is great, but I don't think this helps the querent: They can't simply write a chunk of js code into their objective-c.

Comment: Of course this can help, original question applied to UIWebView, and it has the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method, WKWebView has the `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:`

Comment: Works for me in iPad. +1